# index.php is being downloaded when accessing a WordPress page, running on Docker

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

First time trying Docker (with docker-compose) and the issue I have is that while using a permalink structure like `http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post` instead of `http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123`, when accessing the page link, the `http://localhost/index.php` file is attempted to be downloaded. It's not even the one inside the `/wordpress/` folder, it goes to root level (also have tried to access WordPress as root level, the behaviour is the same).

There are tons of similar issues out there, but supposedly I have the configurations set right.

What may be causing this?

My configurations:

**compose.yaml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - C:/dev:/var/www/html 

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
        - C:/dev:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on; # to enable directory listing 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;      
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**php.Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

**php.ini**

```
date.timezone=Europe/London
max_execution_time=120
upload_max_filesize=40M
post_max_size=40M
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you choose to do it this way? Much simpler and easier using the official [wordpress docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) with docker-compose if you are just wanting to deploy WordPress on localhost. Here are some [docker-compose only wp examples](https://github.com/joshmoto/docker-wordpress-meetup-demo) which might help you out.

Comment: @joshmoto because I'm trying to replace XAMPP; WordPress isn't the only thing I need to run on localhost.

Comment: I understand your are trying to replace XAMPP, your answer probably is not the most elegant. What are the other things you want run on localhost out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, this part:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args =404;
}
```

Should become:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /wordpress/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}
```

Considering I have my WordPress in a subfolder. The `index.php?$args` part is also important for it to work properly.

Not sure this is the most elegant solution but that's what I have for now.